# Quser idle time always returning "none"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm on Windows 7.

To test Quser idle-time response, I made this simple script:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=5 skip=1" %%A in ('quser %USERNAME%') do (echo %%A)
@pause
```

And then created a scheduled task to run this script in 10 minutes. For those 10 minutes I didn't touch the mouse or keyboard.

The result was nevertheless "none".

Anyone have any ideas how I can successfully retrieve the amount of idle-time for the current user in a batch file?

Comment: What output with `"tokens=*"` (and with `skip=1` omitted)?

Comment: I'll get all the columns, but the IDLE TIME column is still "none". @JosefZ

Comment: Then the question seems to be rather [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) topic. Please do not duplicate your question; move it there, or [flag it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834915/quser-idle-time-always-returning-none?noredirect=1#) and ask moderators for moving

Comment: `'quser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Please show sample output. Are you using **BOINC** (a platform to perform scientific research using CPU/GPU idle time) which possibly would assign *its* usage to the user, so idle time may indeed be nil. If you're not using BOINC, why not :)